# Do not create non existent tables

Tags: typeorm

By default, if table that defined in model, does not exist, typeorm would create it. I want all tables to be only created by migrations. If I misspell table name in model declaration, I want some kind of error no be thrown.
Is it possible to turn off auto table creation feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but to turn off *the auto table creation*
you only have to make synchronize to false in configuration file  `synchronize: false,`